# How can I specify the PATH to PhantomJS using GRUNT and QUNIT?

Tags: javascript, path, qunit, phantomjs, gruntjs

Grunt uses PhantomJS to run headless QUnit tests in a very interesting way (correct me if I'm wrong please). Since I just started experimenting with those tools I don't fully understand it and don't know how to configure nor how to extend it.

I manage to get all working on my machine but I would like to **not use** the $PATH system variable. Instead, I would like to provide the path to PhantomJS's executable file via a setting which I could easily change and port to other environments.

How can I achieve this?

I suppose there are many ways and I think the [Qunit Task from Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/tasks/qunit.js) might have an easy answer. Ideally it would be just a matter of defining the path on the *grun.js* file, something like this:

```
qunit: {
      phantomjsPath: 'path/to/phantomjs',
      files: ['test/**/*.html']
    },
```

My environment is a MacOSX but I accept solutions for any kind of environments like Windows - my build server.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** The version of Grunt I am using is *v0.3.17*. The next big version, *v0.4.x*, has many changes and some are not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think you finally migrated onto Grunt 0.4. And propably you got grunt-contrib-qunit plugin for running qunit tests under PhantomJS. Unfortunately you'll encountered the same issue - it's not possible to supply path to phantomjs executable. That's because grunt-contrib-qunit/grunt-contrib-phantomjs use `phantomjs` npm module which downloads PhantomJS on installation and hard-codes path to the executable in its js code. If you're experiencing such an issue then please check my [blog post](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2013/08/issues-with-grunt-contrib-qunit.html).

Comment: Amazing work @Shrike! Thanks for sharing. https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-croc-qunit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, grunt 0.3.x doesn't have a built-in option to specify a path to phantomjs -- it just executes `phantomjs` directly on the command line. Take a look at this helper function:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/tasks/qunit.js#L231

The situation seems to have changed in the has-yet-to-be-released grunt-0.4, however:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/blob/master/lib/phantomjs.js#L22

As you can see, the next version of grunt uses the npm module [phantomjs](https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs) which "exports a path string that contains the `path` to the phantomjs binary/executable.". Since the npm module `phantomjs` is installed locally by grunt, it seems like this would avoid you having to worry about setting the `PATH` variable or installing a conflicting version of `phantomjs`.

Anyway, I'd consider taking a look at [grunt-0.4](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/tree/devel) if you're willing to live on the bleeding edge.

Otherwise, you can always fork the `qunit` task and modify the `grunt-qunit` task to look at your custom configuration variable.

Comment: Thanks @smithclay! That will do. I hope more people will answer this question with solution examples - a.k.a. code - for both version v.0.3.x and v.0.4.x.

Comment: @smithclay, Any update on your answer? any way to have a separate `connect` for qunit`s phantomJS?